# How can I make a "function dictionary"?

Tags: python, syntax, programming-languages

I have lots of functions, and if I have an array `[echo, "Bob is Good"]` I want run the echo function I have with the parameter of the whole array. So it takes `arr[0]` and runs that function with a parameter of the whole array. Right now I just have if statements, for example:

```
...
elif arr[0] == 'echo':
    echo(arr)
elif arr[0] == 'var':
    var(arr)
```

Also, preferably, right now I have my functions set up with a prefix of cmd. For example the echo function would be called echocmd, so if there is a way to implement that, it would be great as well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious way.

```
funcdict = {
  'echo': echocmd,
  'var': varcmd,
   ...
}

 ...

funcdict.get(arr[0], invalidcmd)(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the function directly in the list (they are not arrays; in Python, that means something different):

```
def echocmd(foo, bar, baz):
    print foo, bar, baz # for testing

my_data = [echocmd, 'spam', 'and', 'eggs']
my_data[0](*my_data[1:])
```

Comment: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable - It is converted into string when I split it

Comment: So, replace the string with the corresponding function after splitting, to use this approach. Otherwise look it up when you need to make the call. It depends on what exactly you are doing. If you want people to design something that fits your requirements, you need to provide more information about those requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

- Pass a representative value, ie a string or integer corresponding to the function you want to run. Use a dictionary to index that value to the actual function.
- Pass a reference to the actual function, and use the reference to call it.

The second is more general - you can make up whatever function you like and pass it. The first can let you "sandbox" your interpreter, limiting what functions are allowable, and may also be easier to store externally.